# Does the Print() method in VB.NET work with files opened with Binary access?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, file-io, binaryfiles, ioexception

I am trying to write data to a binary file using the Print() method, but when I run it I get the System.IO exception Bad File Mode. Does anybody have an idea of what's going wrong here? Here's the code for the FileOpen declaration, that might have something to do with it? Thanks

```
FileOpen(filenumber, "path to file", OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Write, OpenShare.LockReadWrite)  
Print(filenumber, expression(variable))
```

Comment: You're asking about the `Print` method, but you've shown a completely different line of code. What `Print` method are you talking about? How are you calling it? Where is *that* code? It's guaranteed to be relevant to this question.

Comment: I supplied the line of code that opens the file because I thought that might have something to do with why I can't call Print()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `Print` in the first place? That function is included for backwards compatibility with VB 6 applications. If you're writing a new application in VB.NET, you should be using a different function.

The easiest way to get off the ground quickly is using the `My.Computer.FileSystem` object to read and write to files. This even provides better performance than the legacy functions like `FileOpen` and `Print`. More explanation and sample code is [available here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y32kbeb6.aspx). Specifically:

- [Reading from Files in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz100x8w.aspx)
- [Writing to Files in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c520bdhb.aspx)

Comment: The reason I'm using Print() is because Write() delimits data with commas, and I need my file interface function to just put out the data that I pass to it (I'm using this to pass assembly code into a .exe)

Comment: @Nate: The suggestion wasn't to use `Write` instead of `Print`. Those are both **legacy** functions, included in VB.NET **only** for backwards compatibility with VB 6 code. New applications should use the standard .NET file I/O functions. They're conveniently exposed to VB programmers with the `My.Computer.FileSystem` object. Read the links in my answer. And pick up a good book on VB.NET: it's a **completely** different language than VB 6, and if you're trying to use them the same way, you're doing yourself and your application a huge disservice.

Comment: Also, I don't know why `Print` isn't working. I've never used it in VB.NET, so I couldn't tell you. What I *am* trying to tell you is that it's a waste of time to try and figure out why it isn't working. Using the right functions in the first place is not only a better idea, but they'll work much better.

Comment: you learn a new thing every day. I don't know the first thing about programming with VB6, VB.NET was my first language. (I do know a little QBasic, though)

Comment: @Nate: Then where are you getting the advice to use functions like `Print`? At this point, the language has been around long enough that no one should still be teaching the legacy functions. Like I said before, if you're learning from a book or an online tutorial, do yourself a favor and find an update one written specifically for VB.NET. The language carries a lot of baggage for backwards compatibility reasons. A great thing if you need it, but not so great for new projects. That's the reason a lot of "professional" programmers dog on VB.NET. It's a great language if you use it the right way.

Comment: The books I've read on VB.NET haven't really touched on file io that much. I just pretty much found that method from digging around in Intellisense.

Comment: So I guess then I don't need to  use FileOpen() to open a file to use My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes()?

Comment: @Nate: Right, the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.writeallbytes.aspx) say this method opens a file, writes to it, then closes it. Which is extremely convenient if you're doing all your writing at once, but if you're adding data to the file in a loop, you should use `BinaryWriter` instead to avoid the overhead of repeated opening and closing. Make sure you check out the samples I linked to. If you're trying to learn to program using IntelliSense (and I'm not knocking it, I did it myself), you have to be familiar with the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Just realized: WriteAllBytes won't work, there isn't any conversion from Char to Byte (Char is the datatype I'm working with). Will anything work with that datatype?

Comment: @Nate: Sure there is. The [`Convert.ToByte` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee6e613x.aspx) has an overload that takes a value of type `Char` as an argument. But remember, chars aren't necessarily bytes in .NET. To convert between textual chars and binary bytes, you need to use an encoding. See the [`System.Text.Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class to do that. Jon Skeet has published [a great article explaining Unicode in the .NET Framework](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx), which is quite relevant here.

Comment: I'm using the Chr() and Asc() functions to bit-shift a file.  The file IO operations are within a loop, so I think the WriteAllBytes would add a little bit too much overhead to the program